# Cannot create release for my contributed module

Tags: 8, community-official-site

I am trying to create a release for my contributed module

https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_facets

I created a tag an that seemed to get trough OK:

git push origin tag 8.x-1.0-RC1

Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

To git.drupal.org:project/taxonomy_facets.git

* [new tag]         8.x-1.0-RC1 -> 8.x-1.0-RC1

I am on the right branch:

git branch

7.x-3.x

- 8.x-1.x

But when I go to "Add new release" page:

https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-release/1334080

In the select "Git release tag or branch" I do not see my release, I only see 7.x branch?

Is there a Drupal git suport email, I tried IRC but no luck, I also tried Drupa forums
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-12-08/cannot-create-release-for-my

Answer (score 2):

There is just a small change that you need to make. The projects on drupal.org are expected to have the releases in lowercase. This is done to support the project infrastructure which is in place like update status and the testing bot.

You should be able to create a new release with a tag like `8.x-1.0-rc1`

More info here : https://www.drupal.org/node/1015226

Comment: @DarkoKantic Glad that worked! Thank you for your contributions :)